# Can the generated signalr hub proxies be bundled with WebPack 2?

Tags: javascript, npm, signalr, webpack-2

I'm in the process of adding SignalR to our AspNetCore MVC site and using WebPack 2 for bundling with npm pulling down required packages.

Normally on a web page I'd add script references to the ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library (v2.2.2), the generated hub proxies (~/signalr/hubs) then any custom scripts to use SignalR.

I'm trying to add these three steps into 1 WebPack entry point.

This is what I have so far:

**webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict";

var path = require('path');
const wwwroot = path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot');
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: ["jquery", "jquery-validation", "jquery-validation-unobtrusive"],

        // Can the generated ~/signalr/hubs be included in the middle of this entry point?
        //                   |
        //                   V
        realtime: ["signalr", './Scripts/App/realtimeBase.ts'],

        main: ['./Scripts/App/main.ts', path.join(__dirname, 'Styles', 'sass', 'site-main.scss')]
    },

    // Other sections removed for brevity ...

};
```

From the example above I've been able to add the jQuery signalr library and the custom typescript but can't figure out how to include the generated proxies (~/signalr/hubs).

Is there a way to do this without having to [create a physical file for the SignalR generated proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy)?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Hi @ChristianGollhardt, apologies, I don't think I did.